# Infinispan 8 clustered-cache

Tags: java, infinispan

I am reading Infinispan docs, currently this example: [ClusteredCache](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/clustered-cache)

Everything looks fine but I wonder if it is possible to have many infinispan configurations? I would like to have many clustered caches and each would use different jgroups parameters, mainly multicast ip and port.

I could cache differently and propagate differently different things..

Answer (score 1):

Caches can have different configurations (expiration, transactions, persistence...) but all caches from one cache  manager share the same JGroups channel, therefore the ports/addresses.

What would you get by using different IPs for different caches? That would only duplicate some resources.

Comment: Each cache for different business region eg user, currencies, systemparameters, these should be subjected to different cache policy

Comment: Yes, but how does cache policy (that's quite vague term) have to do with IPs? If want to isolate access, use Infinispan's Security (check User Guide for that chapter), if you wish to secure the network connections, JGroups have AUTH and ENCRYPT protocols.